# How to get GesturDetector.onSingleTapConfirmed() return value inside onTouch method?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, gesturedetector

I have the following code, which is just setting a `onTouchListener` with `GestureDetector` on a button.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

    final GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            boolean res = gd.onTouchEvent(event);
            Log.i("res", "res = " + res);
            return res;
        }
    });
}
```

}

However, the log shows that the `res` value is always false and never true, meaning that my `onSingleTapConfirmed` callback never pass its return value back to `onTouch()` method.  Any way to get `onSingleTapConfirmed`'s return value inside `onTouch` method?

Comment: How about you write `gd.onSingleTapConfirmed(event);`?

Comment: see [line 300](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java#300) and [line 642](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java#642)

Comment: basically treat `onSingleTapConfirmed` as `void` method - just like `onLongPress` and `onShowPress` - it seems that in the ancient android times `onSingleTapConfirmed` return value was used for something but they decided to change this...

Comment: Have set breakpoints of that source file, only confirm my thought that you cannot get the return value of `onSingleTapConfirmed` inside `onTouch`

Comment: beacuse it is completly ignored by `GestureDetector` - treat `onSingleTapConfirmed` as `void` method,  just like `onLongPress` and `onShowPress`